# Is it semantic for <li> to have block elements like figure, audio, video?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, semantic-markup

I am wondering if `<li>` elements semantically allow for block level elements, like `figure`, `audio`, `video`, etc.?

I couldn't find a definitive answer on searching and the [W3C guidelines seem to not rule it out](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-li-element). But I also haven't seen examples of rich-text-editors allowing it, or pages having that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list item's (`<li>`) [permitted contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) are "flow content". Flow content is made up of:

`a abbr address area (if it is a descendant of a map element) article aside audio b bdi bdo blockquote br button canvas cite code data datalist del dfn div dl em embed fieldset figure footer form h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 header hr i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label main map mark math meter nav noscript object ol output p pre progress q ruby s samp script section select small span strong sub sup svg table template textarea time u ul var video wbr text`

So yes, `<figure>`, `<audio>`, and `<video>` are all technically allowed and valid. Whether there is any semantic meaning is up to your specific HTML.

Comment: I believe the semantics are what the question is asking about, not whether it is allowed.

Comment: @Rob: "Whether there is any semantic meaning is up to your specific HTML."

Comment: @Rob right, and that's subjective. So technically those elements are allowed, but if they have any semantic value would depend on both the full HTML and how it's interpreted.

Comment: @BoltClock My point is, the only part of this that still doesn't answer the question is the last sentence.

Comment: @Rob: I think you mean "the only part of this that answers the question is the last sentence", but I see your point...

Comment: Note that the links go to a Working Draft from 2012, which was intended to be only a (non-normative) reference.

Answer (score 0):

A `<li>` is a list item. If its contents are part of a list then it is properly semantic. Whether the element is block level or not has no play on whether it is semantic. Inline elements can be just as semantically correct as block level (or inline-block).

In your case, it sounds like a list of figures or videos or audio.